# How access the access the whole object by its id

Tags: json, angular

Here we are having two JSON called **1.contacts and 2.workers** contacts json is having id called **serviceId** is nothing but **id of workers**. when i try to display contacts i want to display workers relevant to that contacts. Here is the stackblits **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-tmenv6?file=src%2Fassets%2Fcontacts.json)**

Comment: Can you put the code here? Also what do you mean by workers relevant to the contacts? Does that mean only workers that have their IDs in the contacts object? Or is it by name?

Comment: workers that have their IDs in the contacts object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i have updated stackblitz using sample your data as Array.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-ujzzx1

Code:-

```
let finalResult:any[]=[];
    for(let contact of this.contacts){
      if(contact.serviceId){
        finalResult.push(this.workers.filter(o=>o.id == contact.serviceId));
      }
    }

    console.log("finalResult",finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can gather the IDs from the *contacts IDs* in a map by using `map` then `reduce`. After that you iterate over your *workers* and check in the previously generated map if their `serviceId` is one of the map's keys.

It looks like this

```js
const contacts = [{
    "name": "Jhon Doe",
    "gender": "Male",
    "serviceId":  "e39f9302-77b3-4c52-a858-adb67651ce86",
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter Parker",
    "gender": "Male",
    "serviceId":  "e39f9302-77b3-4c52-a858-adb67651ce86",
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark Wood",
    "gender": "Male",
       "serviceId":  "38688c41-8fda-41d7-b0f5-c37dce3f5374",
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary Jane",
    "gender": "Female",
    "serviceId":  "38688c41-8fda-41d7-b0f5-c37dce3f5374",
  }
];

const workers = [
    {
        "id": "e39f9302-77b3-4c52-a858-adb67651ce86",
        "name": "Alfy Odhams"
    },
    {
        "id": "38688c41-8fda-41d7-b0f5-c37dce3f5374",
        "name": "Allsun Suttle"
    },
    {
        "id": "ed780d15-428b-4bcd-8a91-bacae8b0b72e",
        "name": "Alvinia Ettritch"
    },
    {
        "id": "40665c50-ff74-4e81-b968-e127bdf1fe28",
        "name": "Ambrosi Lindenstrauss"
    }
];

const contactsIDs = contacts.map(c => c.serviceId).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = true;
  return acc;
}, {});

const filteredWorkers = workers.filter(w => w.id in contactsIDs);
console.log(filteredWorkers);
```